# Building Log4cpp with Autotools: pthreads not found

Tags: configure, autotools, log4cpp, pthreads-win32

community,

I downloaded the Log4cpp source package form http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/ and have problems building this library.
To do it, I opened my cygwin-bash.exe, navigated to the root of the source package and typed ./configure. I get a lot of output, but it ends with

> configure: error: unable to find pthreads, currently this is required

Now, I have downloaded POSIX pthreads from https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/ and pasted all dll's into the bin-Folder of MinGW, all headers into the include-Folder of MingGW on all .lib's to the lib-Folder of MinGW, but it still doesn't work.

Can anyone help me? I would appreciate help a lot.

Comment: You could try to generate your own ./configure by running ./autogen.sh first.
That might create different ./configure for your installation. You will need automake, autoconf & libtool installed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't paste libraries or includes to MinGW directories! This will lead to subtle error nobody will understand.

Keep them in an own directory and tell configure were it should look for pthread. Usually that is done with `--with-pthreads` but you can check with `./configure --help`

Comment: If I type ./configure --with-pthreads="C:/Software/pthreads-w32/Prebuilt.2"  I get as first output Warning: unregocnized option --with-pthreads and then the same error as above. The obtions are listed here by the way http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/. I tried also ./configure --with-omnithreads=<My-Path-to-omnithreads> and get error Warning unrecognized option --with-omnithreads